# How to remove a bzr branch?

Tags: software-installation, packaging, bazaar

I'm trying to build a `.dsc` file, and I'm following [this](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html) guide.

I entered the `bzr dh-make` command, but realised I must have entered something wrong, since all the files generated were locked as root (my fault), and I created the wrong resultant files...

Anyway I tried again on the right directory, but I got this error:

```
bzr: ERROR: Either run the command from an existing branch of upstream, or move <program_name> aside and a new branch will be created there.
```

I've tried moving the folder to different places, and executing the `dh-make` command again, but I get the same result.

What should I do?

Comment: What is the exact command you are running and which folder are you running it in?

Comment: Running in `home` and the command is `bzr dh-make resolutionx 1.0 resolutionx-1.0.tar.gz`

Comment: You are running in `/home`? Where is `resolutionx-1.0.tar.gz`? Does the `resolutionx` directory contain any work that you have done?

Comment: resolutionx contains the files for my program, and is structured in the same fashion as it would be if installed - ie. `opt`, `usr`.  I don't have a `tar.gz` file... is that the reason?

Comment: That would be it. `bzr dh-make` extracts `resolutionx-1.0.tar.gz` to `resolutionx`, and it will refuse to do so if `resolutionx` already exists, giving you the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide assumes you have an upstream tarball, and you want to use it to create a bazaar branch and then use it for packaging. The `bzr dh_make` command (`bzr dh-make PACKAGE_NAME VERSION TARBALL`) extracts the tarball to a directory name `PACKAGE_NAME`, and sets it up as a bazaar branch. From [the docs](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/builddeb-plugin.html#dh-make):

> If there upstream is available in bzr then run the command from the
>   root of a branch of that corresponding to the 0.1 release.
>
> If there is no upstream available in bzr then run the command from
>   outside a branch and it will create a branch for you in a directory
>   named the same as the package name you specify as the second argument.

In the second mode, which is what you're using, `bzr` will refuse to extract to an existing directory to create a branch. That's the error you got. Bazaar branches are essentially directories.

The simple workaround (though I have a feeling this is not the intended way) would be:

```
cd /path/to/resolutionx 
# create tarball in parent directory
tar zcf ../resolutionx-1.0.tar.gz -C .. resolutionx
bzr dh_make resolutionx 1.0 ../resolutionx-1.0.tar.gz
```

If you're already using `git` for version control, then look into `git-buildpackage` instead.